# Using Confluent kafka use in xamarin forms

Tags: android, windows, xamarin, xamarin.forms, apache-kafka

I am using confluent-kafka in Xamarin forms it works properly in UWP but in android it giving error like "**Failed to load the librdkafka native library**" while building consumer like,

```
var c = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build()
```